# LinkedList temporary head updating the original head

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a `LinkedList` in `java`. Currently, `LinkedList` contains only  2 methods `insertAtFront` and `insertAtBack` which is working fine. But I want to clear my concept about when we assign a new `Node` to the temporary `head` it is updating the original `head` at the following line.

> headTemp.reference = new Node(data);

How it is happening? Because by default an object is a reference type. Please explain this concept in plain English.

**Node class:**

```
public class Node {

    public int data;
    public Node reference;

    public Node(int data) {
        // Calling the second constructor
        this(data, null);
    }

    public Node(int data, Node reference) {
        this.data = data;
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public Node getNextNode() {
        return this.reference;
    }

}
```

**LinkedList class:**

```
public class LinkedList {

    // Head
    protected Node head;

    // Default head would be null
    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    // insertAtFront first check if head is empty
    public void insertAtFront(int data) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = new Node(data);
        } else {
            head = new Node(data, head);
        }

    }

    // insertAtBack
    public void insertAtBack(int data) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = new Node(data);
        }
        // If List has second node
        else if (head.reference == null) {
            head.reference = new Node(data);
        } else {
            Node headTemp = head;

            while (headTemp.reference != null) {
                headTemp = headTemp.reference;
            }
            headTemp.reference = new Node(data);
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.head == null;
    }

    public void printList() {
        System.out.printf("Linked list is : ");

        Node headTemp = head;

        while (headTemp != null) {

            System.out.printf(" %s ", headTemp.data);

            headTemp = headTemp.reference;
        }

        System.out.printf("\n");
    }

}
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();

        l.insertAtBack(23);
        l.insertAtBack(24);
        l.insertAtBack(25);

        l.printList();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger tofind out what is happening

Comment: @Jens It is updating the original `head` when this line is executed `headTemp.reference = new Node(data)`.

Comment: First of all do not use pubic properties make them private and add getter and setter

Comment: `Node headTemp = head;` does not clone the head. It is only put a reference to head into hedtemp

Comment: @Jens It means it is not pointing to the original head. But then why it is assigning the original head data. What is the behavior behind the scenes happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java variables hold as value (a reference to) the object, the Node instance.
Assignment will share the object.

Hence changes to the object can be reflected in several variables/fields.

Comments on the code, which is very fine on the inserts:

```
public void insertAtFront(int data) {
    head = new Node(data, head);
}

//public LinkedList() {
//    this.head = null;
//}
```

Fields are automatically null, 0, 0.0, false.

The class Node probably need not be public.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you do not understand the Logic of

```
else {
       Node headTemp = head;
       while (headTemp.reference != null) {
            headTemp = headTemp.reference;
       }
       headTemp.reference = new Node(data);
     }
```

First of all the headTemp is a confusing name for the variable , it should be something like tempPointer because what we are doing here is saying i have a pointer which is pointing to the address of a specific node of linked list.

Here the tempPointer is refering to the same variable as head

This is the same logic as

```
String s= new String("ABC");
String s1=s;
```

so both s and s1 as an address of variable new String("ABC");

So our position now is
[Head/tempPointer]-> []-> []-> []-> []-> []

Then because we have address of head we can find address of its next node using tempPointer.reference(the next node address) and say ok i now have the next node address so i dont need the current node address so i will replace.

> tempPointer = tempPointer.reference;

Now it will look like 
[Head]-> [tempPointer]-> []-> []-> []-> []

we do this in a loop until there is no more next node "tempPointer.reference = null" , which is the end of the list.

[Head]-> []-> []-> []-> []-> [tempPointer]

At this point my tempPointer has address of last node so if i add the Node to the end of this address , i will add the node to the linked list

> tempPointer.reference = new Node(data);

[Head]-> []-> []-> []-> []-> [tempPointer]=> [Added Node(new Node())]

Comment: I know the algorithm of LinkedList. But in Java, there is no concept of pointers that is why I'm asking by default java object is a reference type it only updates the original when `new` keyword is used.